# jQuery Custom Event not triggering in AJAX Success Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I am experimenting with jQuery `custom Events` in my Application.

In the jQuery AJAX request code below, in the `success` callback I am trying to `trigger()` my custom `Event`

It does not seem to be triggering it though.  Will this simply not be able to be done in the success callback and needs to be called elsewhere?

**jQuery AJAX request code**

```
// Request Task Record using AJAX Request to Server
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: projectTaskModal.cache.getTaskRecordUrlEndpoint,
    data: {
        action: 'load-task-record',
        task_id: taskId
    },
    success: function(data) {

        // NON RELEVANT CODE REMOVED FOR DEMO

        // Event that is not being triggered....
        // Publish 'task-modal-data-loaded' Event to Subscribers
        $.event.trigger({
            type: 'task-modal-data-loaded',
            source: 'ajax',
            message: 'Task Modal Object Loaded from AJAX Request',
            time: new Date()
        });

    }
}); // end AJAX request
```

**Custom Event Subscriber**

```
$(document).on('task-modal-data-loaded', function(event) {
    //alert('Task Modal Object Loaded');
    console.log('CUSTOM APP EVENTS: Event: task-modal-data-loaded Source: '+event.source+' Message: '+event.message+' Time: '+event.time);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bv8bokus/1/ - make sure the handler is added before the event is triggered

Comment: also just try `$(document).trigger('task-modal-data-loaded')` to test the handler from your console

Comment: @ArunPJohny The trigger and subscriber both work at other locations in the app, just not when the trigger is called from the AJAX success callback.  Also the handler is added before the event is triggered.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bv8bokus/2/ - from any ajax or particular to this one only

Comment: @ArunPJohny I hadn't tried any other however I just made a JSFiddle similar to yours, except using the actual code from my question here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/h9apvcww/ and it is not triggering in this one either

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h9apvcww/2/ - in jsfiddle you have used `echo/html` with dataType as `json` that was the problem so the success method is never called... are you sure yours is getting called..

Comment: Also why the `async: false`

Comment: @ArunPJohny That was my mistake on the fiddle but in my app it is called as other logs are executed and code ran.  as for the `async: false` option, that was because my App can't really proceed until the data from this AJAX request is received and I was trying to delay other code from running that relies on this data to instantiate other parts.  I'm still learning so I have read the alternative is to use `promises` and stuff like that which is really confusing still so for now `async: false` solved my issue

Comment: sorry other than that, I'm out of options without a reproducible example....

Comment: To add to the mystery, this same Event Trigger and Subscriber have another trigger that is ran if my data is loaded from the dom from a click event and that catches the event with no issue.  It is only when it is called from the ajax response that it fails.  I'm doing more tests now

Comment: do you have a test environment that is exposed to internet

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think I got it...related to your first comment...I have an `init()` function ran that detects if should load data from existing DOM nodes or from AJAX...if it needs to do AJAX it then triggers that call which triggers my event all before the rest of my init events ca even be defined!  So it is in fact triggering before my subscriber.  Took a while to realize do to the complexity of my app, it;s about 4,000 lines so far and growing.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to help... it is sometimes those silly issues...

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sure enough that did the trick!  It seems to **ALWAYS**  be a minor issue with a huge problem and sometimes hours down the drain!  Nearly 15 years as a backend developer, I am really thoroughly enjoying what I can do with JavaScript on the frontend now in 2015, it's a lot more fun working with IMO

Comment: @ArunPJohny Do you mind posting your answer of making certain the subscriber callback function is defined before the Trigger() is called so I can select it as the answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion, The problem is when the event is triggered the handler is not yet added to the dom.

So making sure that the event handler is added before the event is fired will solve the probelm

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just `.trigger()` ?
[jQuery trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

from their docs:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

So for your implementation:

```
$(document).trigger('task-modal-data-loaded',[{
        source: 'ajax',
        message: 'Task Modal Object Loaded from AJAX Request',
        time: new Date()
    }]);
```

And the listener:

```
$(document).on('task-modal-data-loaded', function(event,data) {
//alert('Task Modal Object Loaded');
    console.log('CUSTOM APP EVENTS: Event: task-modal-data-loaded Source:    '+
      data.source + ' Message: ' + data.message + ' Time: ' + data.time);
});
```

Comment: I have tried both syntaxes as both are listed on the referenced jQuery docs page however neither are fired off when called in my success callback.  If I call them anywhere else in the app they do work though.